# Operator overloading for making a set of elements of type pair<int, int>

Tags: c++, set, operator-overloading

How do I overload the '<' (less than) operator for pair of ints to insert the elements of this type into set. For example, consider the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utility>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

bool operator<(pair<int, int> a, pair<int, int> b){
  if(a.second < b.second) return true;
  if(a.second == b.second) return a.first < b.first;
  return false;
}

int main(){
  pair<int, int> a = make_pair(1, 4);
  pair<int, int> b = make_pair(2, 3);
  set<pair<int ,int> > s;
  s.insert(b);
  s.insert(a);
  set<pair<int, int> >::iterator it = s.begin();
  for(; it!=s.end(); it++){
    printf("(%d %d)\n", it->first, it->second);
  }
  if(a < b) printf("a < b\n");
  else printf("b < a\n");
}
```

The output produced by the above code is:

```
(1 4)
(2 3)
b < a
```

I want the elements of the set to be ordered by the second element of the pair structure. How to do this?

Comment: `std::pair` already has `operator <` defined.

Comment: Sounds to me like what you might want to do is add a side effect to your '<' overloaded implementation, where you have a set attribute of a comparator class, and you add items to the set every time the '<' operation is called. Sounds a little dangerous to me, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::set` maintains an order between its elements (each value is also its own key and thus it must be unique).

You cannot sort a `std::set` and subvert this ordering but you can define your own ordering criterion

```
struct sortBySecond {
  bool operator()(const pair<int, int>& e1, const pair<int, int>& e2) const {
    if (e1.second < e2.second)
      return true;
    else if (e1.second == e2.second) {
      if (e1.first < e2.first)
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }
    else
      return false;
  }
};


int main() {
  pair<int, int> a = make_pair(1, 4);
  pair<int, int> b = make_pair(2, 3);
  set<pair<int, int>, sortBySecond> s;
  s.insert(b);
  s.insert(a);
  for (auto& el : s)
    std::cout << "(" << el.first << ";" << el.second << ")" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51b38e547288a075)</kbd>

Comment: You may simplify your compare function with `return std::tie(e1.second, e1.first) < std::tie(e2.second, e2.first);` (`std::tie` may be replaced by `std::make_pair` here).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `std::set` uses `std::less` internally for its comparisons and that delegates to the `operator<` of `std::pair` provided by the Standard Library. This will order your pairs lexicographically on `first` and then `second`.

However, you also pull in the entire `namespace std` and provide your own `operator<`. At the point where you do `if(a<b)`, name lookup will find your own provided comparison and use that. This is why you got contradictory results.

You can write your own function object `my_less` and pass it to `std::set`. I'd recommend to use `std::forward_as_tuple` for it, but the implementation you provided is OK as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <utility>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

struct my_less 
{
    bool operator()(pair<int, int> const& a, pair<int, int> const& b) const
    {
        return std::forward_as_tuple(a.second, a.first) < std::forward_as_tuple(b.second, b.first);
    }
};

int main(){
  pair<int, int> a = make_pair(1, 4);
  pair<int, int> b = make_pair(2, 3);
  set<pair<int ,int>, my_less> s;
  s.insert(b);
  s.insert(a);
  set<pair<int, int> >::iterator it = s.begin();
  for(; it!=s.end(); it++){
    printf("(%d %d)\n", it->first, it->second);
  }
  if(my_less{}(a,b)) printf("a < b\n");
  else printf("b < a\n");
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/).